# JQuery backgroundcolor changes (either .animate or .css) only work once after restart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, background-color

Hi everyone I've got a huge issue that I don't quite understand why it's happening.

The thing is, I got the jquery plugin jquery.color so that I could change 4 div's color alternately each 6 seconds so that when the first one is white, the others are black, when the second is white the others are black and so forth.

When I started out programming it everything was working and I thought I was making progress but I tried it again and nothing... I decided that maybe it was the jquery color plugin's fault so I decided to give jquery UI plugin a go. I emptied the caches and restarted the mac, tried the "new" plugin and it was working again so I started to program a little more, tried it again and BAM same thing happens...

The weird thing is that the exact same code works after a restart but does not work a second time...

I've got the following jquery plugins on use: jquery.urlrewrite, jquery.easytabs, jquery.ae.image.resize and of course jquery-ui.

The small snippet of .JS code that I am using for testing purposes is:

```
var intervalo = window.setInterval(caneco, 6000);

function caneco(){


$("#triangulo").animate({
top: "120px"
}, 1000 );

$("#juntaimg").animate({
left: "-451px"
}, 1000 );

$("link1").animate({
  'background-color': "black"
}, 1000);


}
```

Weirdest of all, all other animations aside from backgroundColor changes work perfectly and everytime...

Can anyone help me out?? Please??

Comment: can u please put it in http://jsfiddle.net ? with the initial html and css it will help.  (+1 for being portuguese)

Comment: You can shorten `window.setInterval(caneco, 6000);` -> `setInterval(caneco, 6000);`

Comment: yes, but it will not change any errors...

Comment: i found one error already, being that link1 should be #link1, however it still does not work... I'm gonna try the jsfiddle. As for being portuguese wait some more time and you'll start seing the names of the functions changing to things even worse!

Comment: lol, seriously now, you should keep programming "in english". it's way easier for people here to understand what you are trying to accomplish so we can help

Comment: Here's the jsfiddle, it works fine overthere but still I wonder why it's not working fine overhere... http://jsfiddle.net/QjAUE/

Forgot to add that I'm using my own mac as a server on apache with php and mysql working, that's going to be a data-based centered website built on mysql (small max number of users).

Comment: @LIMsomnium can you open a javascript console, on your testing environment, and see if you catch any javascript errors?

Comment: All I have to try right now is firebug, do you suggest anything else?

Comment: no errors detected... the only strange thing is that #link1 gains a style="" over at the <div> tag... not sure why though...

Comment: i edited that line, try it like that

Comment: Found the problem... It's somehow on updates.php the file I was loading through jquery's .load I don't know what's messing it up, but something is... Gonna find it out... Tomorrow though... need some rest. Thanks a lot for you help André! Probably tomorrow I'll put the updates.php on jsfiddle and share it here if I can't find the solution.

Comment: don't bother putting it on fiddle, it doesn't take php. put it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for anyone that has this problem it was due to a conflict between the index.php and the update.php which was being loaded using jquery's .load into a div. Since I developed everything independently and afterwards joined it I had jquery 1.7.1 being loaded two times, had some php scripts being loaded twice and so on... So basically I solved it all by using a restrained .load like this:

```
$("#finalcontainer").load("updates.php #initialcontainer");
```

and then I just moved all the css of that page to the index css file (I know I should have done it already but that bug was killing me!) and also I moved all the .js animations of updates.php to the index.php.

So that's how I squashed my bug. And mainly it was my fault all along...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully working jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/VjFMj/

I corrected / changed it a bit (e.g. intervals and the animation descriptions) but that should not be a major thing - if it works, your code should work.

If this works for you and your local version doesn't, try making a small example like this - just include the jQuery and jQuery UI and the code from the jsFiddle and see if that works. If it does, it's probably some typo / missed tag or any other syntax error that's making it not work.

Btw, you probably want `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, as the latter will repeat the call every n milliseconds, while `setTimeout` runs it once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the work! I'll try something simpler like that to see if it works. I did want setInterval since the purpose is to make the change occur to all the 4 div's one by one each 6 seconds but thanks a lot!

Comment: Tried the small test you made with no problems whatsoever on my local server under test.php... So now I just have to find the reason for the bug on my index.php... not an easy task... any hints on what could cause such a behaviour?

Comment: Found the problem... It's somehow on updates.php the file I was loading through jquery's .load I don't know what's messing it up, but something is... Gonna find it out... Tomorrow though... need some rest. Thanks a lot for you help icyrock! Probably tomorrow I'll put the updates.php on jsfiddle and share it here if I can't find the solution.